# Update ArrayList from another Activity without access into it

Tags: android, android-fragments, arraylist, android-activity, navigation-drawer

this is my question:

1) I have a `FragmentA` where I get `String value` from a `TextView` through a `Button`

2) I pass the `String value` to my `MainActivity` through a `Button setOnClickListener`

(I want to specify: when I click the `Button` I continue to stay inside `FragmentA`)

3) Now from `MainActivity` I pass the `String value` to my `FragmentB`

(I use `Intent` and `Bundle` to pass the `String values between activities`)

Arrived at this point its all ok, I managed to pass the `String value` from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`.

4) sample code of `FragmentB`:

```
ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView=(ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
ObjectListAdapter adapter = new ObjectListAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.listview_activity, arrayList);

Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

if(bundle!=null){
value = bundle.getString("Code");
Object object = new Object(value);
arrayList.add(object);
arrayList.setAdapter(adapter)
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

This is my problem:

If I click the `Button` from `FragmentA` (with `TextView` compiled) and I go to check to `FragmentB`, the `ArrayList` was created with one element

(If I repeat this the `ArrayList` keep updating normally)

BUT if I click the `Button` from `FragmentA` (with `TextView` compiled) and I don't go to check to `FragmentB` and instead I click again the `Button` (with `TextView` compiled), the `ArrayList` was created not with 2 elements but just with 1 element, the last added.

How can update my `ArrayList` from another `Fragment` without access into it?

Comment: I want to know if it is possible or not, thanks.

Comment: Possible show me code when you show fragmentB in activity

Comment: How can I share you my code?, its very long @CôngHải

Comment: Just code you perform fragment transaction to show fragment B not full code in fragmentB

Comment: 1. We should create method in Activity 2. In fragmentA call it 3. From activity we find instance of fragmentB and update list

Comment: I dont use fragment transaction

Comment: You using navigation or declare it in xml?

Comment: If you want i have my project on github

Comment: Ok put your link

Comment: https://github.com/ArnoldKumaraku/OOP_AndroidAPP.git

Comment: sorry I cant commit and push my last update

Comment: ok now its all ok

Comment: @CôngHải please take the updated project

Comment: worst case scenario - fire a `Broadcast` via the `BroadcastManager` and have a `BroadcastReceiver` in the class which needs to be externally updated.

Comment: @CôngHải ok I got it, I solved the problem

Comment: @CôngHải sorry for waste your time

Comment: @KKKKK don't mention it